# Solr - identical search result scores for multiple search terms?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, edismax

I would like to know how it is possible to get different scores for a multiple terms search result?

Certain results in solr have the same score even when there are multiple terms in the query as you will see in the example below.

I have two indexes in Solr, each containing: id, first_name, last_name
Each index would look like the following:

```
<doc>
    <str name="id">1</str>
    <str name="last_name">fisher</str>
    <str name="name">john</str>
</doc>

<doc>
    <str name="id">2</str>
    <str name="last_name">darby</str>
    <str name="name">john</str>
</doc>
```

When I query just "john" both results come up. That is perfect. 
However, when I query "john fisher" both results come up but with the same score. 
What I want is different scores based on the relevancy of the search terms.

Here is the result for the following query
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=john+fisher%0D%0A&rows=10&fl=*%2Cscore

```
<response>
    ...
    <result name="response" numFound="2" start="0" maxScore="0.85029894">
        <doc>
            <float name="score">0.85029894</float>
            <str name="id">1</str>
            <str name="last_name">fisher</str>
            <str name="name">john</str>
        </doc>

        <doc>
        <float name="score">0.85029894</float>
            <str name="id">2</str>
            <str name="last_name">darby</str>
            <str name="name">john</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do check this out: [Search in two fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_search_for_.22superman.22_in_both_the_title_and_subject_fields)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to understand & analyse how different factors affect your document score, Lucene has helpful feature `Explanation`, Solr leverage this to provide how scoring is calculated you can use 'debugQuery' in Solr to see how it is derived,

```
?q=john&fl=score,*&rows=2&debugQuery=on
```

Ex Response:

```xml
<lst name="debug">
    <str name="rawquerystring">john</str>
    <str name="querystring">john</str>
    <str name="parsedquery">+DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:john))</str>
    <str name="parsedquery_toString">+(text:john)</str>
    <lst name="explain">
        <!-- Score calulation for Result#1 -->
        <str>
            2.1536596 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(text:john in 36722), product of:
            1.0 = tf(termFreq(text:john)=1)
            8.614638 = idf(docFreq=7591, maxDocs=15393998)
            0.25 = fieldNorm(field=text, doc=36722)
        </str>
        <!-- Score calulation for Result#2 -->
        <str>
            2.1536596 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(text:john in 36724), product of:
            1.0 = tf(termFreq(text:john)=1)
            8.614638 = idf(docFreq=7591, maxDocs=15393998)
            0.25 = fieldNorm(field=text, doc=36724)
        </str>
    </lst>
```

besides this, you can use `explainOther` to find out how a certain document did not match the query.

```
?q=john&fl=score,*&rows=2&debugQuery=on&explainOther=on
```

**Do Read:**

- [Solr Relevancy](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ)
- [Lucene Scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/scoring.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are only searching on the "name" field. Thats why the scores are the same. If you use [DisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMax) you can easily search on both fields and the most relevant will have a higher score.

e.g.

```
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
<str name="qf">name last_name</str>
```

Another way is to combine the 2 fields into 1 field with copyField and only search in the newly created field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply guys, I appreciate that.

From the explain query I was able to identify that indeed the search was only been performed on one field alone.

I saw that it is possible to add multiple fields to the same field for searching. 
In the schema.xml I added the following:

```
<copyField source="last_name" dest="text"/>
```

The results now come up as expected when using more than one search term.